# Trying to turn JSONP data from AJAX response into HTML

Tags: ajax, node.js, jsonp

The response is coming through to the browser in the developer tools, but I'm having trouble getting the data from the response that I want into workable form.

app.js

```
res.jsonp({
                pollName: loadedPoll.pollName,
                pollTitle: loadedPoll.pollTitle,
                pollID: loadedPoll._id,
                pollOptions: loadedPoll.pollOptions
            });
```

javascript

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://Thisiscorrect.com:3000/loadPoll',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data:{questionName: 'testPoll'},
        success: function(data){ //console.log(data);
            var X = data.toString();

            console.log(X);
            //console.log($(x).filter("#responseText"));
        }
```

If I look in the developer console at the data

`responseText: "jQuery19105805847404990345_1364409899124 && jQuery19105805847404990345_1364409899124({↵  "pollName": "testPoll",↵  "pollTitle": "Do you like Doritos?",↵  "pollID": "5150a7596a76e6378a000002",↵  "pollOptions": [↵    "Yes",↵    "No",↵    "Maybe"↵  ]↵});"`

Which is what I want but neither of the two methods up there work. Any advice?

Comment: Where is your node.js code? Can you go through your question and make it a little bit clearer? Why are you doing data.toString?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I added my response from server side. What I am trying to send a request to the server to get a specific Poll that can be turned into HTML. I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of data.tostring,try

```
JSON.stringify( data)
```

Comment: gotta wait 3 minutes. I won't forget.

Comment: I didn't know there was a time limit!